# flutter | How to check whether document is present in firestore or not

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

Here i want to check whether a document is present in firestore or not, if present it should execute 'if' part otherwise 'else' part, i have used document id same as user id, this is what i got so far:

```
    class MapScreenState extends State<DashboardPage> {
      FirebaseUser user;
    
      Stream<DocumentSnapshot> getData() async*{
        user = await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser();
        yield* Firestore.instance.collection('Profile').document(user.uid).snapshots();
      }
    
      bool present = false;
    
      checkIfPresentOrNot() async{
        DocumentSnapshot ds = await Firestore.instance.collection("Profile").document(user.uid).get();
        this.setState(() {
          present = ds.exists;
        });
      }
    
      @override
      void initState() {
        super.initState();
        checkIfPresentOrNot();
        getData();
      }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: getData(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (present) {
          var userDocument = snapshot.data;
           return new showProfile(
            name: userDocument['name'],
            email: userDocument['email'],
            pin: userDocument['pin'],
            address: userDocument['address'],
          );
        }else{
         return new showProfile(
           name: "",
           email: "",
           pin: "",
           address: "",
         );
        }
      },
    );
  }
}
```

But when i run this code only the else part executes even if the document is present in firestore. How can i resolve this issue?

Comment: Umm.. I'm not sure if it will work or not, but give it a shot., 1) movecheclIfPresentorNot() below getData() in the initState(), second, remove "this" from this.setState()

Comment: It does not work